# как добавить в дочернюю активити Layout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Есть две активити: `GameActivity` и `ApplicationView`.

Мне нужно, чтобы в `GameActivity` указывался файл layout XML, в котором была прописана `ApplicationView` активити.

Как обычно это делается через `setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);`, но что-то не получается.

Вот код `GameActivity`:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);
        //setContentView(new ApplicationView(this));//изначально было это
    }
```

Вот код `ApplicationView`:

```
public class ApplicationView<yLine> extends View {
    public ApplicationView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        canvas = new Canvas(image);//рисовалка на канве
        canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
```

Приложение работает отлично.
Посоветовали использовать `AttributeSet`, но я не смог понять, что и как указывать.

Вот код лэйаута:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <com.rdt.touched.game.ApplicationView
        android:id="@+id/game_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

нашел решение ---

все заработало

вот код

private Level2 view;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);

```
   RelativeLayout layout = 
           (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_relativelayuot);
            view = new Level2(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout); 
            layout.addView(view, 0);
}
```

и во View

public Level2(Context context, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, RelativeLayout layout) {
            super(context);

Comment: `ApplicationView` это не активити, а вью. Что именно у вас не работает, или работает не так, как надо?

Comment: Активити - это класс, который наследуется от класса `Activity` (extends Activity, AppBarActivity, Fragment Activity и подобных), и ничего больше.  Соответственно ваш вопрос выглядит абсурдным и не имеет ответа. Разберитесь с тем, что как называется и отредактируйте вопрос.

Comment: Да, это вьюшка ... Я в терминах немного путаюсь. Новичок.

Answer (score 2):

Делается это через include. Пример.

```
<include layout="@layout/Ваш View" />
```